# Using Azure Durable Functions with a CosmosDBTrigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-durable-functions

I have a data pipeline that is reading the change feed from CosmosDB and loading the data into an external resource via Durable Functions. My start function (in Python) looks something like this:

```py
import azure.durable_functions as df
import azure.functions as func


async def main(documents: func.DocumentList, starter: str):
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new('MyDFOrchestrator', client_input=documents)
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration ID {instance_id}")
```

However, this runs into an error because the `cosmosDBTrigger` passes in a list of Cosmos Documents but `client.start_new()` needs a JSON-serializable input value. I can get around this by shoving the list into a simple JSON object (like `{"doc_list": [{doc1}, {doc2}, {doc3}]}`) but I want to make sure I'm not missing something in the API to handle this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to pass JSON as input value to the orchestrator. There is an example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/tree/dev/samples/serialize_arguments) which does similar. Though the example is with http trigger, but the concerned area here has nothing to do what trigger you use at the starter/triggering Function.

Alternatively, you can create a concrete serializable class holding the model/entity structure (much cleaner than raw json). To create serializable classes, all we require is for your class to export two static methods: to_json() and from_json(). The Durable Functions framework will interally call these classes to serialize and de-serialize your custom class. Therefore, you should design these two functions such that calling from_json on the result of to_json is able to reconstruct your class.